# Printing part of an array in MiniZinc

Tags: minizinc

I have a MiniZinc model for wolf-goat-cabbage in which I store the locations of each entity in its own array, e.g., `array[1..max] of Loc: wolf` where `Loc` is defined as an enum: `enum Loc = {left, rght};` and `max` is the maximum possible number of steps needed, e.g., 20..

To find a shortest plan I define a variable `var 1..max: len;` and constrain the end state to occur at step `len`.

```
constraint farmer[len] == left /\ wolf[len] == left /\ goat[len] == left /\ cabbage[len] == left
```

Then I ask for

```
solve minimize len
```

I get all the right answers.

I'd like to display the arrays from `1..len,` but I can't find a way to do it. When I try, for example, to include in the output:

```
 [ "\(wolf[n]), " | n in 1..max where n <= len ]
```

I get an error message saying that I can't display an array of `opt string`.

Is there a way to display only an initial portion of an array, where the length of the initial portion is determined by the model?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to fix the len variable in the output statement like `n <= fix(len)`?. See also [What is the use of minizinc fix function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697137/what-is-the-use-of-minizinc-fix-function)

Comment: Terrific! That did it. Thanks.